# Body is Empty on Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new to angular / node js . I am trying to create a simple login page, i have a problem at this point, the data i pass from angular shows up as empty on node side

Angular code

```js
var app = angular.module('trial', []);
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.submitLogin = function(){
 var loginUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/performLogin'
 var formData = {
  'username' : $scope.name,
  'password' : $scope.pwd
 };
 var jdata = 'loginInfo=' + JSON.stringify(formData);
 var config = {
  headers : {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
  }
 }
 alert('in' + jdata)
 $http.post(loginUrl, jdata, config)
 };
});
```

Node side

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('login.html', { root: __dirname + "/trial/" } );
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/trial'));
app.post('/performLogin', jsonParser, function(req, res){
 try
 {
  console.log(req.body);
 }
 catch( e )
 {
  console.log( ' Exception while trying to perform Login Operation: ' + e.message );
 }
});

app.listen(8080);
```

On console i get {} while trying to print body

Comment: Wouldn't just be `app.post('/performLogin', function(req, res){...`?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong middleware. You are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but are only parsing `application/json` requests.

Add `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests.

Comment: Hi, i tried your suggestion still no good. Please find the code snippet which i have attached as an answer below.

Comment: edited the original question above as per  Skelly suggestion